# Test driven development on iOS for network connections

Tags: ios, testing, tdd

Struggling to find a good TDD process on iOS for network connection tests.

At the moment I am manually testing the functionality by manually switching off / on my Mac network connection.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show an example test case?

Comment: Don't try to test the whole flow.  See if you can simulate a disconnected network by returning error and having separate error handlers.  Then you can just test the error handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are test-driving, I would remove the real network from the picture.  I'd mock out the API which returns an error code or throws an error (Kiwi has a nice ability to replace real methods during tests) to force it to respond the way you'd like.

If you're not sure how the API will respond in your circumstance, I would spike that using network link conditioner or other methods with copious logging in your program.  Once you determine how the condition looks to your program, go back to TDD with mocks.

It's often useful to wrap the network API with your own class to give you a more stable thing to mock.

Comment: I guess then that it's not possible to test the very end of this chain though. You can keep pushing the chain further and further back but eventually something has to speak to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Network Link Conditioner. You can download it from developer.apple.com